# How do I set correctly vertical align middle on image

Tags: html, css

Example I have set the master div with `100px` the height. In the div have one logo which I want it to be `vertical-align:middle;`

Here an example http://jsfiddle.net/c7Me7/

I want the logo will be auto align to middle without have a `padding` or `margin`.

Output should be like

[image]

Let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED: This works.

```
#top { height:100px; background:#000; padding:0 20px;line-height:100px;}
#logo img {vertical-align: middle;}
```

see - http://jsbin.com/utuye5/2

Comment: nice. Thanks Joe! set line-height and without `> div > a >` works too. http://jsfiddle.net/c7Me7/9/

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this page, it advices on several ways to solve this.

http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

Comment: that article says it does not work in IE. I tried it in IE9 beta, and it does work there :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/c7Me7/7/

use text-align:center

Comment: hmmm.. you know how `vertical-align:middle` will looks like?

Answer (score 0):

```
#top { height:100px; background:#000; padding:0 20px;position:relative}
#logo {position:absolute;top:30% }
```

Try this `top` can be adjusted as per need

Thanks,
Amit